# How do I change Material UI Autocomplete font size?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying apply custom css to the Material UI Autocomplete component. Specifically, I want to change the font size of the input field. Here's what I have right now:

```
<Autocomplete
  style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 60,
    marginLeft: 15,
  }}
  options={["foo", "bar"]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 30 } }}
      {...params}
      margin="normal"
    />
  )}
/>
```

I believe that my TextField is being styled properly, but it's CSS is being overwritten by the Autocomplete CSS. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You could try 2 of those things,

1. Swap these two lines

```
InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 30 } }}
{...params}
```

to be

```
{...params}
InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 30 } }}
```

This is because the second `{...params}` override the `InputProps`.

2. You can change the `Inputprops` CSS with the `!important` marker as the following:

```
InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: `30 !important` } }}
```

3. You need to put spreader `params.InputProps` in `InputProps` to ensure showing autocomplete options:

```
InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, style: { fontSize: `30 !important` } }}
```

Comment: @PriyankDeepSingh In case you still haven't found a solution, please have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is still searching for an answer, this is how to correctly apply CSS properties to the input element according to the [Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/).
With this method you leverage the possibility of providing classes to underlying elements of the autocomplete component.

```
<Autocomplete 
size={"small"} 
id="box" options={myOptions} 
getOptionLabel={(option: string) => option} 
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" /> } 
classes={{ input: classes.smallFont }} />
```

Instead of "input" you could for example specify a class for "inputRoot" to set a class at the input root element (depending on what you want to achieve)

Comment: This overrides the Input text size but doesn't override the Label text size if you have the label attribute inside the TextField component (e.g. label="Select Value").  Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @reactive-core Well, I can't test it at the moment but I would assume that since the TextField is its own component you could just use the "usual" ways according to the TextField API https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api. Especially "InputLabelProps".

Comment: Indeed, that was it.  I kept looking for label props in the Autocomplete, not realizing it was in TextField (sorry I'm just learning).  Setting InputLabelProps={{className: classes.inputLabel}} and inputLabel with a font size change in the makeStyles() call fixed it up.  Thanks!

Comment: For me its worked in option 
classes={{option: classes.autocompleteOptions}}

Answer (score 1):

You can change className from params in renderInput function

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({     
    comboOptions: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: 'red'
    }
}));


    <Autocomplete key={index}
    size="small"
    value={combo.value}
    options={combo.options}
    renderOption={(option) => (
        <Typography className={classes.comboOptions}>{option.name}</Typography>
    )}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    renderInput={(params) => {
        params.inputProps.className = classes.comboOptions
        return <TextField
            {...params} label={combo.text}
            variant="outlined"
        />
    }
    }
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        combo.onChange(newValue)
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had requirement to increase font size of lable and I have solved it by following way

**Solution:**

```
TextFieldProps={{
    error: props.error,
    helperText: props.helperText,
    InputLabelProps: {
        required: props.required,
        style: {
            fontSize: 18,
        },
    },
}}
```

**Detailed Solution:**

```
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    fullWidth={true}
    label={props.label}
    margin={'noraml'}
    multiple={false}
    name={props.name}
    isOptionEqualToValue={useCallback((option, value) => option.label === value.label, [])}
    value={props.value}
    options={props.options}
    ref={selectRef}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    disabled={props.disabled}
    TextFieldProps={{
        error: props.error,
        helperText: props.helperText,
        InputLabelProps: {
            required: props.required,
            style: {
                fontSize: 18,
            },
        },
    }}
    renderInput={useCallback(params => (
        <TextField {...params} variant='standard'/>
    ), [])}
    onChange={useCallback((e, v) => {
        if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
            _onChange(e, v)
        } else {
            _onChange(e, {label: ''})
        }
    }, [])}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        renderOption={(option) => (
          <Typography style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }}>{option.title}</Typography>
        )}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, style: { fontSize: "1rem" } }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).