# How to change options font size in Material UI Version 5 Autocomplete?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to change the font size of the drop down items.

I tried different ways of changing font size as follows,

[How do I change Material UI Autocomplete font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492939/how-do-i-change-material-ui-autocomplete-font-size)

[How to change fontsize of options in Material ui autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963549/how-to-change-fontsize-of-options-in-material-ui-autocomplete)

But those ways are not working for me, hope it is due to they are for version 4.

Here is my Autocomplete component.

```
<Autocomplete
   size="small"
   disablePortal
   options={getVisaOptions()}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField  {...params} label="Select VISA"/>}
/>
```

Comment: Font size of which part of component? drop down items? header? input?

Comment: Drop down items

Answer (score 4):

it worked with customizing `renderOption`

```
<Autocomplete
    size="small"
    disablePortal
    options={getVisaOptions()}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
    renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box style={{fontSize: 14}} {...props}>
            {option.label}
        </Box>
    )}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField  {...params} label="Select VISA"/>}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I got here from your prior post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963549/how-to-change-fontsize-of-options-in-material-ui-autocomplete when I was having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

About your question, you could set renderOption and set style for the option font size, here is my example you can try.

```js
<Autocomplete
   size="small"
   disablePortal
   options={getVisaOptions()}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField  {...params} label="Select VISA"/>}
   renderOption={(props, option) => (
             <Typography sx={{fontSize: 18}}>
                {option.label}
             </Typography>)
            }
/>
```